# How do you create a user creatable / editable content type in orchardproject.net cms

Tags: .net, orchardcms

I'm customizing an OrchardProject.net cms.  I'd like the users to be able to submit a "deed".  It's a simple ContentType with a single text field.

This is a piece of cake for a user with admin rights but I want a regular user without access to the admin panel to create it.  Users can submit comments, but there are a lot of hoops to jump through to follow that model.  (Record, part, controller, viewModel, views, etc..)

I would think the default system provides this but I can't figure out the route get it to generate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give a **Role** the ability to create and publish "Deed" content on your site, you can go into Roles (Dashboard -> Users -> Roles tab in Orchard 1.1) and give various permissions to a role (existing or new). Then, you would assign the role to a user.

After adding a Content Type called **Deed** (be sure to include the **Common** Part), the Roles tab allows the following permissions:

Publish or unpublish Deed for others
Publish or unpublish Deed
Edit Deed for others
Edit Deed
Delete Deed for others
Delete Deed

So, for example:

1. Create a Role, **DeedCreator** with the two "Publish or unpublish..." permissions (in the Deed section
2. You will also need to grant "Access admin panel" permissions in the Orchard.Framework section
3. Create a user, **User1** with DeedCreator role

Even though you granted Access admin panel permissions, the user will only be able to access the Create Deed page in the dashboard--nothing else.

If you want to allow Anonymous users (really, really, really **not** recommended), you could technically grant the aforementioned permissions to the Anonymous role. Keep in mind, Anonymous users would then have at least a surface-level angle of attack to your dashboard. Any user could navigate to www.yoursite.com/admin and start creating Deed content.

**Update per comment**

When I *Saved* my test Deed, here's what the POST to **/Admin/Contents/Create/Deed** looked like:

```
Body.Text:<p>test useraddable add (save)</p>
Deed.UserField1.Value:blah blah
CommentsActive:true
CommentsActive:false
CommonPart.Owner:admin
CommonPart.ContainerId:
submit.Save:submit.Save
```

Plus, there was a value for __RequestVerificationToken, which I'm not sure how to generate. (Maybe with the `Html.BeginAntiForgeryPost` helper in the Orchard.Mvc.Html namespace

Comment: Ok, that gets me 80% of the way there, thx!  Ultimately, I'd like to have them be able to submit a "Deed" from the site itself.  What value for "action" do I have for the form element?  "~/Admin/Contents/Create/Deed"?  Is there a route like "~/Contents/Deed/Create" or "~/Contents/Create/Deed"?

Comment: @DanielEli Were you able to confirm the value for __RequestVerificationToken works by using `Html.BeginAntiForgeryPost`? If so, I would say you have the details to hack the same POST generated by the Dashboard :)

Comment: haven't dug into that yet.  Would you be able to pair on this?  I want custom controller now.  I did everything else with codegen extensions.  I can pay.  (I hope this isn't against SO policy!)  twitter:@danschlossberg  github:danieleli